# What is causing my computer to lockup/freeze during the Blender rendering process?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm currently using Blender version 2.93.1 and the file I'm working on uses experimental mode for adaptive subdivision using cycles. I've been running into computer freezes and lockups that force me to hard shut down my computer. They happen whenever I'm rendering and always during the BVH calculations before rendering the samples. While looking at task manager during these renders, it says that Blender uses up 99% of the available memory during rendering. I have 16GB of RAM. Before the computer locks up, Blender drops from around 7500mb to 500mb and then the whole system locks up.

Do you have an idea of what could be the cause?

Comment: Adaptive subdivision is a pretty heavy feature. It adds a lot of geometry when you are too close to the object. I would recommend you to stay far away from the object in the view and decrease the dicing rate if you don't have very high quality hardware.

Comment: Are you using a low poly mesh ? Maybe you set bump to displacement only and there's not enough geometry to see it